# Hiding and Showing Quiz Questions with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a quiz that asks the user 6 questions. Some questions display the answer options as a dropdown. Others use radio buttons. Some questions also show tips below the form field.

At the end of the quiz, the quiz will add up the score based on the previous answers and tell the person if he or she is at risk of a heart attack.

What is the best way to display the questions and their tips (if they have them)? Keeping them in the HTML file and hiding and displaying with JavaScript? Or moving the questions and options into an array in the JS file - in which case, how would I control which form inputs the question generates?

Or something else?

Here are the questions that are in the HTML:

```
<section class="questions">
    <h2 class="outline">Question</h2>

    <p class="questionNumber">Question 1 of 5</p>

    <div class="questionAge">
      <p class="questionText">What is your age range?</p>

      <form>
        <select>
          <option value="20-34">
            20-34
          </option>

          <option value="35-39">
            35-39
          </option>

          <option value="40-44">
            40-44
          </option>

          <option value="45-49">
            45-49
          </option>

          <option value="50-54">
            50-54
          </option>

          <option value="55-59">
            55-59
          </option>

          <option value="60-64">
            60-64
          </option>

          <option value="65-69">
            65-69
          </option>

          <option value="70-74">
            70-74
          </option>

          <option value="75-79">
            75-79
          </option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div><!--end questionAge -->

    <div class="questionCholesterol">
      <p class="questionText">What is your total cholesterol?</p>

      <form>
        <select>
          <option value="Less than 160">
            Less than 160
          </option>

          <option value="160-199">
            160-199
          </option>

          <option value="200-239">
            200-239
          </option>

          <option value="240-279">
            240-279
          </option>

          <option value="Greater than 279">
            Greater than 279
          </option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <div class="tip">
        <p>Don't know your total cholesterol? Attend one of our free
        screenings. <a href="http://www.chsbuffalo.org/events" target=
        "_blank">Click here to view upcoming screenings in our events
        calendar.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end cholesterol -->

    <div class="questionSmoker">
      <p class="questionText">Are you a smoker?</p>

      <form>
        <input name="smoker" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes<br>
        <input name="smoker" type="radio" value="No">No<br>
      </form>
    </div><!-- end questionSmoker -->

    <div class="questionHDL">
      <p class="questionText">What is your high-density lipoprotein (HDL)
      cholesterol level?</p>

      <form>
        <select>
          <option value="60">
            60
          </option>

          <option value="50-59">
            50-59
          </option>

          <option value="40-49">
            40-49
          </option>

          <option value="Less than 40">
            Less than 40
          </option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <div class="tip">
        <p>HDL cholesterol is also known as “good” cholesterol. If you
        don’t know your HDL level, ask your doctor for a cholesterol
        test.</p>

        <p>Don’t have a doctor? <a href=
        "http://www.chsbuffalo.org/physicians">Click here to find a primary
        care doctor near you.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end questionHDL -->

    <div class="questionMed">
      <p class="questionText">Are you on blood pressure medication?</p>

      <form>
        <input name="medication" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes<br>
        <input name="medication" type="radio" value="No">No<br>
      </form>
    </div><!-- end questionMed -->

    <div class="questionSBP">
      <p class="questionText">What is your Systolic Blood Pressure reading
      (first number)?</p>

      <form>
        <select>
          <option value="Less than 120">
            Less than 120
          </option>

          <option value="120-129">
            120-129
          </option>

          <option value="130-139">
            130-139
          </option>

          <option value="140-159">
            140-159
          </option>

          <option value="Greater than 159">
            Greater than 159
          </option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <div class="tip">
        <p>Don't know your blood pressure? Attend one of our free
        screenings. <a href="http://www.chsbuffalo.org/events" target=
        "_blank">Click here to view upcoming screenings in our events
        calendar.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end questionSBP -->

    <form name="next">
      <input type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
  </section><!-- end questions -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic way of doing it

jquery:

```
$(":input").change(function(){
    $(this).parents("div").addClass("hideMe");
    $(this).parents("div").next("div").removeClass("hideMe");
});
```

to make this work i made a new `class` called `"hideMe"` which all but the 1st question have to start with, but as it is selected/answered the `function` above then adds that `class` to the current `select/input`s parent `div` and removes said `class` from the next `div` containing a question

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/rf3ewn0p/) showing how it works

hope this helps and gets you on track

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to create the entire CSS declaration in jQuery but this seems like a simpler solution.

Comment: How would I do this if I want to keep the next button? In this case, I could no longer use "this" because the click would be on the next button.

Comment: If you create a 2nd new class called "questionContainer" and apply it to the divs where it currently uses "hideMe" in the above code change the selector that is used to `.questionContainer` rather than `div` which you would need to do for a live site anyway here is a http://jsfiddle.net/rf3ewn0p/1/ showing it with the modification

Answer (score 0):

You have a wealth of design choices.  My vote is to keep your "data" separate from your "display logic".  You may wish to add or remove or change the data months from now and if that data is in some external file that can be loaded, you will be much better off.  You can also load your data dynamically from your web site using Ajax calls.

Your next puzzle would be what format to store the data in.  JSON is easiest for JavaScript processing but XML or even plain text (maybe with a markup processor) would also work.

I also understand that there are many pre-existing "Quiz" processors available for free.

If you wish collaboration when creating questions and answers, consider storing the data in some form of database engine which again is likely to be available on your web site.  You could then provide a "front-end" that users could use to populate/edit the questions.